# Play sound in Combobox in C#

Tags: c#, combobox, uwp

I'm new in C# programming, I created a combobox with items and I want that items to play sound when i chose one, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdDCS.png), 
[or that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gthc.png)

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Could would be in methods play1 and play2

```
private void AudioComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (AudioComboBox.SelectedIndex == AudioComboBox.Items.IndexOf("Sali 3la Mohammed 1"))
            {
                play1();
            }

            else if (AudioComboBox.SelectedIndex == AudioComboBox.Items.IndexOf("Sali 3la Mohammed 2"))
            {
                play2();
            }
        }


        private void play1()
        {
        }
        private void play2()
        {  
        }
```

Comment: What is your question? Specify what you need to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
private void AudioComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (AudioComboBox.SelectedIndex == AudioComboBox.Items.IndexOf("Sali 3la Mohammed 1"))
            {
                play1();
            }

            else if (AudioComboBox.SelectedIndex == AudioComboBox.Items.IndexOf("Sali 3la Mohammed 2"))
            {
                play2();
            }
        }


        private void play1()
        {
            SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer("sound1.wav");
            simpleSound.Play();
        }
        private void play2()
        {  
            SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer("sound2.wav");
            simpleSound.Play();
        }
```

Comment: SoundPlayer is not available for UWP apps as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MediaElement` or the new `AudioGraph` to play sounds in UWP.

`MediaElement` is the simpler approach, which has the disadvantage of causing the music stop on Mobile devices, so it is really not too appropriate your purpose.

```
MediaElement player = new MediaElement();
var stream = await yourSoundFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
player.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
player.Play();
```

`AudioGraph` is specifically created for sound effects in UWP apps and is the best choice for you. There is a [quick and simple tutorial on Loek van den Ouweland's blog](http://loekvandenouweland.com/content/using-audiograph-api-in-windows-10-apps.html), so I definitely recommend you to check it out. Basically you need to create an `AudioGraph` instance and with it `AudioFileInputNode`s for each of the sounds you need.